# Why finding chromatic number is NP-Hard?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete

We know that the chromatic number of a graph $G$ is the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of $G$ so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color .

But why the coloring is NP-HARD ? and what is the difference between it and vertex coloring ?
[image]

Comment: Do you know what NP-Hard means in terms of theoretical computer science ?  It essentially means that any problem in NP can be transformed  so it becomes the problem of finding the chromatic number of a graph. And can you define vertex coloring ?  As far as I know, it's the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I know, but why this problem 'Chromatic Coloring' is NP-Hard ?

Comment: Even determining whether the chromatic number is $\le 3$ (that is, whether a given graph is 3-colorable) is NP-hard. You can find several descriptions of the standard reduction from CNF-SAT by googling for [3-coloring np-hard](https://www.google.com/search?q=3-coloring+np-hard).

Comment: One reason is that the number of colorings we have to try grows very  very fast and we don't have a clear way of deciding which colorings are "worth trying".

Comment: @Henning Makholm why it is NP-Hard not NP-Complete, I think it is NP-COMPLETE

Comment: @TandeeHolwa: 3-colorability is NP-complete. "NP-complete" means that it is both NP-hard and in NP (and it is trivially obvious that 3-colorability is in NP). On the other hand, "computing the chromatic number" is not a decision problem, and therefore the concept of NP-complete doesn't even apply to it.

Comment: So is that to know if the problem is NP-Complete or NP-Hard, then if it is not decision problem then it must be NP-Hard + NP-Complete?
Or all NP-Complete problems are also NP-Hard?

Comment: All NP-Complete problems are indeed NP-Hard (NP-Complete problems are the "hardest problems" in the class NP while NP-Hard problems are "at least as hard" as those in the class NP).

Answer (score 1):

A decision problem A is NP-hard means that if you can solve A in polynomial in **input size**, you can solve any NP problem in polynomial time (in input size). The mechanism to convert a problem B to a problem A (in polynomial time) is called a reduction from B to A.

3-COLOURABILITY
Input: A graph G
Question: Is G 3-colourable (i.e., is $\chi(G)\leq 3)$ ?

The problem 3-COLOURABILITY is NP-hard because there is a polynomial time reduction from 3-SAT to 3-COLOURABILITY and there is a reduction from SAT to 3-SAT. It is proven that if you can solve SAT in polynomial time, you can solve any NP problem in polynomial time (Cook's theorem). Hence, checking if chromatic number is at most 3 is hard and therefore finding chromatic number exactly must be hard as well.

Note: (Read this in case you get interested in reductions)
You can find a reduction from NAE SAT to 3-COLOURABILITY more easily (i think so).

Comment: The first sentence of this is often found in popular treatments, but is slightly incorrect. As written it would be satisfied by _any_ problem outside P, but if P≠NP then there exist NP-intermediate problems, which by definition are neither in P nor NP-hard. Instead, NP-hardness is defined explicitly by the existence of (poly-time many-one) reductions.